# why does glossaries fail on the SECOND `\mathbf`?

Tags: glossaries, boldmath

For some odd reason `glossaries` fails to print the glossaries list when there's more than one bold notation... here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronyms,section]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{svm}{svm}{support vector machine}
\newacronym{yw}{yw}{support vector machine}

\newglossaryentry{v}
{
name={$\mathbf{v}$},
description={velocity [km/s]}
}

\newglossaryentry{r}
{
%name={${r}$}, %this works
name={$\mathbf{r}$}, %this does not
description={position [km]} 
}

\begin{document}
blah blah blah \gls{svm}, \gls{yw},  \gls{v} and \gls{r}
\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

I **KNOW** I'm not the first to use `glossaries` or multiple notations that are bold (using `mathbf`), so what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glossaries` chokes when sorting; add the `sort` key.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronyms,section]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{svm}{svm}{support vector machine}
\newacronym{yw}{yw}{support vector machine}

\newglossaryentry{v}
 {
  name={$\mathbf{v}$},
  sort={v},
  description={velocity [km/s]},
 }

\newglossaryentry{r}
 {
  name={$\mathbf{r}$}, %this does not
  sort={r},
  description={position [km]} 
 }

\begin{document}
blah blah blah \gls{svm}, \gls{yw},  \gls{v} and \gls{r}
\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow ! that was fast and efficient, many thanks !

Comment: Did you see my profile? *Pronto prontissimo son come il fulmine: sono il factotum della città.* `;-)`